# Call to a member function file() on array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

sigo editando el formulario de registro que trae el AUTH de Laravel y necesito tener la posibilidad de enviar un archivo al storage y guardarlo con el registro del cliente.

Bien como decia utilizo el formulario de registro de laravel:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf


<input id="modelos" type="file" class="form-control @error('modelo') is-invalid @enderror formContact" name="modelos" value="{{ old('modelos') }}" autocomplete="modelos">
```

Yo lo que estoy haciendo para añadir más campos es entrar en `RegistrerController` y añado las validaciones y el `create` y luego también añado los campos en el modelo `user`.

Pero estoy añadiendo esto dentro de `RegistrerController`:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        
        return User::create([

            $data->file('modelos')->store('modelos'), //Esto es lo que añado
            
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'tipo_id' => 3,
            'cif' => $data['cif'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'apellidos' => $data['apellidos'],

            $slugName = Str::slug($data['name'], '-'),
            $slugApellido = Str::slug($data['apellidos'], '-'),
            $slugLetras = Str::slug($data['letrasEmail'], '-'),
            $slug = $slugName.'-'.$slugApellido.'-'.$slugLetras,
            'slug' => $slug,
            'pais' => $data['pais'],
            
            'telefono' => $data['telefono'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),


                'codigo' => $data['codigo'],

        ]);
    }
```

Añado el file pero me devuelve un error.

```
Call to a member function file() on array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notoriamente tu variable `$data` es un array. Tu archivo está dentro de ese array y debes acceder a él tal y como lo haces con los otros atributos. Esto retornaría tu archivo:

```
$data["modelos"];
```

No sé si estés recibiendo una instancia File o el contenido del archivo en esa variable, pero la lógica para almacenar un archivo sería prácticamente la misma.

```
Storage::putFile('modelos', $data["modelos"]);
// ----
$data["modelos"]->store('modelos');
```

Dependiendo de lo que recibas, será como debas guardar el archivo. Pero tu error radicaba principalmente en que el método `file()` puede ser accedido desde archivos y estás intentado llamarlo desde un array.

Comment: Gracias @L.Flor, funciona perfectamente!!